# A question for train lovers (a specific part of a steam locomotive)

Tags: terminology, translation

I am currently translating a text concerning steam locomotives (from Slovak to English) and I am a little bit stuck on an issue with a certain part of a steam locomotive (in the red circle). [image]

Is there a specific name for that part? Like some kind of plate which helps to rectify the steam?

My second question is directly connected with the first one. Thanks to this particular part, the locomotive got its name, with these parts symbolizing "ears", therefore, the locomotive is called "Ušatá" in Slovak, which can be literally translated as "The one with ears" or "The one with big ears". Is there a word in English that would perfectly describe this attribute?

Any kind of help/answer will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You might also try your luck at proz.com, a translation portal.

Comment: Yeah, I am also considering the proz.com, but I also wanted to post it here, because I have been browsing through this website for quite a while and always found some helpful or relevant information.

Comment: In [action](http://youtu.be/CMHKReB8u-U). At first I thought you were talking about the round logo in the middle of your cicle - I thought it was a vent part of the [kylchap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylchap) exhaust system. But you mean the whole black flap.

Comment: I am sorry, I should make the circle much more visible. I mean the whole black flap as you said, it is some kind of plate which was installed later, and the locomotive was named after that.

Comment: I don't know much about the internals of locomotives, but assuming the *engine* is under that plate (or that in some way it's a "protective cover") you might call it a ***cowling***.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't think that the primary feature of this plate was to protect the engine. I have found a German equivalent: "das Ablenkblech". Unfortunately, I still cannot find the proper English form.

Comment: Is it [smokebox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokebox) ?

Comment: No, the picture can be somehow confusing, but this certain part is separated from the smokebox, there's approximately 0,5 metres space between this plate and smokebox

Comment: @vnkstl: Isn't it the side of smokebox? The whole part is called smokebox. I don't see how the part you show is a different part. I found some sources calling it "smokebox side".

Comment: Oh ok, it is in front of the sides of the smokebox. But I think not all locomotives have that?

Comment: Well it is a beautiful piece of history, that is true :) No, not all locomotives had that. As far as I am concerned, the main function of these plates was to direct the smoke from the smokestack when the locomotive was ascending to the hill.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the English Wikipedia, they are called *smoke deflectors*:

> **Smoke deflectors**, sometimes called "blinkers" in the UK because of their strong resemblance to the blinders used on racing horses, are vertical plates attached to the front of a steam locomotive on each side of the smokebox. They are designed to lift smoke away from the locomotive at speed so that the driver has better visibility. [[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_deflectors)]

(I guess the "blinkers" idea would be analogous to the Slovak "ears" image that you mention.)

Comment: Well done! I was specifically checking this Czech 475-179 steam locomotive: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/475-179_czech_steam_locomotive_2007_05_12.jpg

Comment: @ruakh Sir, you just made my day :) Thank you very much for your answer, I did not suppose that these things could be called "blinkers". The analogy between the blinkers and "ears" could also work, thank you :)

Comment: Smoke deflectors were sometimes called "elephant ears" in the US, according to the Wikipedia article s.v. Smoke Deflector.